# gitlab CI and r issue with using manual and manual rules together

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, rules

I am trying to setup CI in gitlab so

1. the second job (**pushdev**) will be available for running manually only after the **devjob** has run successfully.
2. the third job **pushtostage** will only run iff file has changed.

the way the jobs are setup, second and third jobs alway run. What is missing in the pipeline spec

```
devjob:
  image: node:16
  stage: publishdev
  script:
    - echo "running validation checks"
    - npm run validate
  rules:
    - changes:
        - ./src/myfile.txt
    - when: manual


# - this jobs needs to run after "devjob" has run successfully
# and myfile.txt has changed
# - "needs" artifacts from the "lint" job 
pushdev:
  image: node:16
  stage: publishdev
  needs: [ "devjob", "lint"]
  script:
    - echo "Pushing changes after validation to dev"
    - npm run pushdev
  rules:
    - changes:
        - ./src/myfile.txt
      when: on_success
    - when: manual

pushtostage:
  image: node:16
  stage: pushstage
  script:
    - echo "Pushing changes to stage"
  rules:
    - changes:
        - ./src/myfile.txt
    - when: manual
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change your sample to look like [this](https://gitlab.com/mouson-gitlab-playground/demo-workshop/tryci/-/blob/try-rules-stackoverflow-72594854-manual/.gitlab-ci.yml):

```yaml
stages:
  - publishdev
  - pushstage

default:
  image: ubuntu:20.04

lint:
  stage: publishdev
  script:
    - echo "lint job"

devjob:
  stage: publishdev
  script:
    - echo "running validation checks"
  rules:
    - changes:
        - README.md
      when: manual
      allow_failure: false

pushdev:
  stage: publishdev
  needs: [ "devjob", "lint"]
  script:
    - echo "Pushing changes after validation to dev"
  rules:
    - changes:
        - README.md
      when: manual
      allow_failure: false

pushtostage:
  stage: pushstage
  script:
    - echo "Pushing changes to stage"
  rules:
    - changes:
        - README.md
      when: manual
      allow_failure: false
```

1. I add `allow_failure: false`, because [allow_failure](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#allow_failure) when manual job default is true.
2. I merge your rules. because [GitLab rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) one `-` is one rule:

> Rules are evaluated when the pipeline is created, and evaluated in order until the first match.

your .gitlab-ci.yml first job `devjob` is manual, so it is always a success, and your second job `pushdev` first rule changes and `when: on_success` always match, so it always run.

I change your .gitlab-ci.yml, first job `devjob` merge your rules when file change and set it is manual job and not allow_failure. and so on.

the sample code in [Files · try-rules-stackoverflow-72594854-manual · GitLab PlayGround / Workshop / Tryci · GitLab](https://gitlab.com/mouson-gitlab-playground/demo-workshop/tryci/-/tree/try-rules-stackoverflow-72594854-manual)